# How to do a react build, when react-scripts is marked as dev-dependency

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

There is some license issue with one of the dependencies getting installed with react-scripts.
Project is created using CRA, so react-scripts is marked as dependency in package.json.

If I mark react-scripts as dev-dependency, since i don't need it for production, and install all the packages using 'npm install --production', I will not be able to use build script as react-scripts is not installed.

Browsing around this I see react-scripts should ideally be a Dev-dependency.

So just wanted to check if anyone can help here, how to use build script keeping react-scripts as Dev-dependency? is using webpack as a to bundle would be the only option here?

Answer (score 4):

NPM and package.json initially were created for Node.js, which is intended to either run some scripts, or to run continuously. In this cases you might need some dependencies only when you are developing (for example some debuggers, or nodemon and so on), but don't need them in production.

In case of CRA, you don't need *any* dependencies on production, since you are building bunch of static files. Generally, you have some build pipeline, that will install *all* dependencies, build your static files and then transfer only built files to produciton (where only production dependencies may be installed again, or it can be another build step in pipeline). If you don't have such pipeline, you can install *all* dependencies, build on server and then delete `node_modules`.

Comment: Thanks @Mr Hedgehog, yup we have a pipeline, problem is because of some policy even we are not able keep these troubling packages for bundling as well. Webpack looks to be the way for now.

Comment: Yes, if you can't use this packages, you will have to build your own pipeline. It might be a good idea to [make your own template for CRA](https://auth0.com/blog/how-to-configure-create-react-app/) if you use it often

Comment: That helps, Thanks!